# How can i make my labels and textfields appear in a borderlayout in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, border-layout

How can i make my Jtextfiels, Jlabels,and JtextArea appear in the borderlayout? I wanted to make my label1 in the north, textarea in the east and the rest in the west.The problem is that they don't appear and my textfield seems to be squeezed in the left.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ReliefFrame extends JFrame
{
    ReliefCenter s = new ReliefCenter("JavaCup");
    JPanel row;
    JPanel roww;
    JPanel rowww;
    JPanel rowwww;
    JLabel Label1;
    JLabel Label2;
    JLabel Label3;
    JLabel Label4;
    JButton[] button=new JButton[5];
    JTextField aTextField;
    JTextField bTextField;
    JTextField cTextField;
    JTextArea aTextArea;
    public ReliefFrame() {
        super("ReliefCenter");
        setSize(700, 700);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible( true );
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        Label1= new JLabel("Welcome to JavaCup Relief Center");
        add(Label1);

        createNorthPanel();
        createEastPanel();
        createWestPanel();
        createSouthPanel();
        createaTextField();
        Label2= new JLabel("Relief Good",JLabel.LEFT);
        add(Label2);
        createbTextField();
        Label3= new JLabel("Quantity",JLabel.LEFT);
        add(Label3);
        createcTextField();
        Label4= new JLabel("Unit",JLabel.LEFT);
        add(Label4);
        createButton();
        createBButton();
        createCButton();
        createDButton();
        createEButton();
        createTextArea();
        add( row, "East" );
        add( roww, "West" );
        add( rowww, "North");
        add( rowwww, "South");
    }

    private void createNorthPanel()
    {
        rowww = new JPanel();
        rowww.setLayout( new BorderLayout( ) );
    }
    private void createEastPanel()
    {
        row = new JPanel();
        row.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    }
    private void createWestPanel()
    {
        roww = new JPanel();
        roww.setLayout( new GridLayout(6,1) );
    }
    private void createSouthPanel()
    {
        rowwww=new JPanel();
        rowwww.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));
    }
    private void createaTextField()
    {
        aTextField = new JTextField( "" );
        roww.add( aTextField );
    }

    private void createbTextField()
    {
        bTextField = new JTextField( "" );
        roww.add( bTextField );
    }

    private void createcTextField()
    {
        cTextField = new JTextField( "" );
        cTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);
        roww.add( cTextField );
    }
    private void createTextArea()
    {
        aTextArea = new JTextArea("" );
        aTextArea.setEditable(false);
        row.add(aTextArea);
    }   

    private void createButton()
    {
        button[0] = new JButton( "Add Good" );
        class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
        { 
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
            {
                String a = aTextField.getText();
                String b = bTextField.getText();
                String c = cTextField.getText();
                int d=Integer.parseInt(b);
                s.addNewGood(a,d,c);//
                aTextField.setText( "" ); 
                bTextField.setText( "" );
                cTextField.setText( "" );
                aTextArea.append("Added new good: "+a+"\n");           
            }
        }
        button[0].addActionListener( new ButtonListener() );
        rowwww.add( button[0] ); 
    }
    private void createBButton()
    {
        button[1] = new JButton( "Receive Goods" );
        class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
        { 
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
            {
                String a = aTextField.getText();
                String b = bTextField.getText();
                int d=Integer.parseInt(b);
                s.receiveGoods(a,d);//
                aTextField.setText( "" ); 
                bTextField.setText( "" );
                aTextArea.append("Received "+a+":"+d+"\n");                
            }
        }
        button[1].addActionListener( new ButtonListener() );
        rowwww.add( button[1] ); 
    }
    private void createCButton()
    {
        button[2] = new JButton( "Release Packs" );
        class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
        { 
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
            {
                String a = bTextField.getText();
                int b=Integer.parseInt(a);
                s.releasePacks(b);
                bTextField.setText( "" );           
            }
        }
        button[2].addActionListener( new ButtonListener() );
        rowwww.add( button[2] ); 
    }
    private void createDButton()
    {
        button[3] = new JButton( "Packs Released" );
        class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
        { 
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
            {
                int a=s.getPackCount();
                aTextArea.append("JavaCup has released"+a+"packs. \n");         
            }
        }
        button[3].addActionListener( new ButtonListener() );
        rowwww.add( button[3] ); 
    }
    private void createEButton()
    {
        button[4] = new JButton( "Inventory Report" );
        class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
        { 
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
            {

                aTextArea.append("===INVENTORY===\n");
                s.printInventory();
                aTextArea.append("===============\n");

            }
        }
        button[4].addActionListener( new ButtonListener() );
        rowwww.add( button[4] ); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    ReliefFrame c = new ReliefFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: 'ReliefCenter' class code ? meains how have you draw it ?

Answer (score 1):

`BorderLayout` works based on the `preferredSize`.
Therefore, try this to test it out:

```
    ...
    add( row, BorderLayout.EAST );
    add( roww, BorderLayout.WEST );
    add( rowww, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add( rowwww, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    row.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    roww.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    rowww.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    rowwwww.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
}
```

Also, you are adding the labels without specifying constraints, so the `LayoutManager` doesn't know what to do.

So, try this for your labels:

```
labelPanel = new JPanel();
labelPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());

Label1= new JLabel("Welcome to JavaCup Relief Center");
labelPanel.add(Label1);

createNorthPanel();
createEastPanel();
createWestPanel();
createSouthPanel();
createaTextField();
Label2= new JLabel("Relief Good",JLabel.LEFT);
labelPanel.add(Label2);
createbTextField();
Label3= new JLabel("Quantity",JLabel.LEFT);
labelPanel.add(Label3);
createcTextField();
Label4= new JLabel("Unit",JLabel.LEFT);
labelPanel.add(Label4);

add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Note that I put a `GridLayout` in the `JPanel`. You may use whatever `LayoutManager` suits you best. I just went for the simplest one for the example

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does Jlabel work the same as Jtextfield in terms of placement?

Comment: They are all `JComponent` from the point of view of the container, in your case the `ReliefFrame` content pane. Your issue is that you are adding the labels without declaring contraints. I will edit my answer to exemplify better

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems:

1. Don't use magic values. "East", "West"... are all magic values that are not defined anywhere. Instead use the variable provided by the API. BorderLayout.EAST, BorderLayout.WEST ...
2. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your variables are correct and some are not. Be consistent!!!
3. Using methods that don't return the components you create is not a good idea. There is no need to define instance variables for all the sub panels. They should all just be local variables.
4. Your variable names (row, roww, rowww, rowww, label1, label2) are terrible. Nobody has any idea what that refers to. Names should be descriptive if that are to be reused throughout the code.
5. Components should be added to the frame BEFORE you use pack() and setVisible(true).

So a better structure for your code might be something like:

```
add(createNorthPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(createWestPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
...
pack();
setVisible( true );
```

Then the code for createNorthPanel() might be something like:

```
public JPanel createNorthPanel()
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel quantity = new JLabel("Quantity");
    panel.add(quantity);
    JLabel unit = new JLabel("Unit");
    panel.add( unit );

    return panel;
}
```

Now all the logic for creating one panel is contained in one place.

You also should not be extending a JFrame, but instead add components to a panel and then add the panel to the frame. I suggest you read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for working code that demonstrates this approach.